# Attempting to add more buttons dynamically to my JavaFXML project

Tags: java, rest, javafx, gson, fxml

The coursework requires us to create a graph, which displays RESTFUL data from a server in JavaFX. The file I have is one we recieved from the tutor, who never really explained how he achieved the finished result. So I am just wondering how, within this Java Fxml project, I code the controller to add dynamic buttons?

The buttons that are called already are check boxes, when they are selected they display cars that are for sale in the bar chart. I would like to add buttons that let me choose the year of sales, and also add functionality to hard coded buttons which switch from a bar chart to a line graph.

***FXML Code***

```
<AnchorPane id="" fx:id="AnchorPane1" prefHeight="-1.0"    prefWidth="-1.0"    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="salescwck3.SalesController">

<children>
  <VBox spacing="10.0">
     <padding>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
     </padding>
     <children>
        <HBox fx:id="HBox1" spacing="10.0">
           <padding>
              <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
           </padding>
        </HBox>
        <HBox fx:id="HBox11" spacing="10.0">
           <padding>
              <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
           </padding>
        </HBox>
        <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" prefHeight="19.0" prefWidth="217.0" spacing="10.0">
           <padding>
              <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
           </padding>
           <children>
              <RadioButton fx:id="RadioButton1" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Bar Chart" />
              <RadioButton fx:id="RadioButton2" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Line Graph" />
           </children>
        </HBox>
        <BarChart fx:id="BarChart1" animated="false" title="Vehicle Sales">
          <xAxis>
            <CategoryAxis label="Region" side="BOTTOM" fx:id="xAxis" />
          </xAxis>
          <yAxis>
            <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis" label="Quantity of Sales"   side="LEFT" />
          </yAxis>
        </BarChart>
     </children>
  </VBox>
 </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

***Main Java***

```
package salescwck3;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SalesCwck3 extends Application {    
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root =    FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SalesController.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
      scene.getStylesheets().add(SalesCwck3.class.getResource("Style.css").toExternalForm());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("SalesCwck3");
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}    
}
```

***FXML Controller***

```
public class SalesController implements Initializable {
private static String markup;
private static List<Sales> sales;
private static List<String> vehicles;
private static List<Integer> year;
private DashService service;

private CheckBox[] checkBoxes;

private ChoiceBox[] choiceBoxes;

@FXML
private RadioButton RadioButton1, RadioButton2;    
//Need to learn how to switch from bar chart to line graph

@FXML
private AnchorPane AnchorPane1;

@FXML
private HBox HBox1;
//Contains The Check Boxes constructed for vehicles

@FXML
private HBox HBox2;
//Populate this with the year Choice Box

@FXML
private NumberAxis yAxis;

@FXML
private CategoryAxis xAxis;

@FXML
private BarChart<?, ?> BarChart1;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    service = new DashService();
    service.setAddress("http://glynserver.cms.livjm.ac.uk/DashService/SalesGetSales");
    service.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent e) {
            markup = e.getSource().getValue().toString();                
            sales = (new Gson()).fromJson(markup, new TypeToken<LinkedList<Sales>>() {}.getType());


            vehicles = sales.stream().map(o -> o.getVehicle()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
            year = sales.stream().map(o -> o.getYear()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

            // ToDo : Debugging !
            System.out.println(markup);

            for (Sales sale : sales) {
                System.out.println(sale.toString());
            }           

            constructCheckBoxes();


        }
    });



    service.start();
}       

//Need a Progress Loader.



private void constructCheckBoxes() { 
    checkBoxes = new CheckBox[vehicles.size()];

    for (byte index = 0; index < vehicles.size(); index++) {
        checkBoxes[index] = new CheckBox(vehicles.get(index));
        checkBoxes[index].setSelected(true);
        checkBoxes[index].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {                    

                constructSeries();
            }
        });

        HBox1.getChildren().add(checkBoxes[index]);
    }

    // NOTE : More Controls Visible !
    AnchorPane1.getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();

    constructSeries();
}

private void constructSeries() {
    BarChart1.getData().clear();

    for (CheckBox checkBox : checkBoxes) {
        if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
            XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
            series.setName(checkBox.getText());

            // NOTE : Java SE 7 Code !
            for (Sales sale : sales) {
                if (sale.getVehicle().equals(checkBox.getText())) {
                    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>( sale.getRegion(), sale.getQuantity()));
                }
            }

            BarChart1.getData().add(series);
        }
    }
}

/*
private void constructChoiceBoxes(){}
//Trying to create another choice box in order to choose which date of sales are shown on the graph.
//Need to know where to put the "constructChoiceBox()" and "constructChoiceSeries()" Code for year Choice Boxes.
private void constructChoiceSeries(){}
*/



private static class DashService extends Service<String> {
    private StringProperty address = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public final void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address.set(address);
    }

    public final String getAddress() {
        return address.get();
    }

    public final StringProperty addressProperty() {
       return address;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<String> createTask() {
        return new Task<String>() {
            private URL url;
            private HttpURLConnection connect;
            private String markup = "";

            @Override
            protected String call() {
                try {
                    url = new URL(getAddress());
                    connect = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    connect.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    connect.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    connect.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");                        

                    markup = (new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()))).readLine();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    if (connect != null) {
                        connect.disconnect();
                    }
                }

                return markup;
            }
        };
    }
}
}
```

***Gson Java***

```
public class Sales {
final private int Year, QTR, Quantity; 
final private String Region, Vehicle;

public Sales(Integer Year, String Region, Integer QTR, String Vehicle, Integer Quantity) {
    this.Year = Year;
    this.Region = Region;
    this.QTR = QTR;
    this.Vehicle = Vehicle; 
    this.Quantity = Quantity;         
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s%s%s%s%s", ("Year:" + Year + " "), ("Region:" + Region + " "), ("QTR:" + QTR + " "),("Vehicle:" + Vehicle + " "), ("Quantity:" + Quantity + " "));
}
public Integer getYear() {
    return Year;
}
public String getRegion() {
    return Region;
}
public Integer getQTR() {
    return QTR;
}
public String getVehicle() {
    return Vehicle;
}
public Integer getQuantity() {
    return Quantity;
}
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.Reword question. "So I am just wondering how, within this Java Fxml project, I code the controller to add dynamic buttons?" You wanna add another controller? Another fxml? What is dynamic button in your mind? Its reallu unclear to me even how you want it to look like , have you tryed anything?

Comment: Well I guess would just like to understand how I should go about creatting another set of buttons, which holds the ability to filter the graphs data. Showing the Year and Qtr of the sales, if you have a look at the controller you will see hat "ConstructCheckboxes()" has the ability to filter the region and the quantity of the sales.